# gpupdate fails, access denied - event ID 1055

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy

I became aware of this issue yesterday after pushing out GPO for Software Policy Restrictions.  I am unable to push out MSI installations to certain computers. I went to look at the one of the machines, and it is affecting computers that are not governed by this policy. It was not the cause of the problem.

After trying to run a gpupdate on an affected machine, I saw that it was failing with the message that access is denied citing DNS errors. After checking the event log, it shows an error with the Event ID of 1055.  Nothing dealing with permission or access levels has been altered in any way unless they have some sort of infection.  This has yet to be determined.

I have verified that DNS is working properly from one of the machines.  I verified the DNS registration for the machine and it showed no errors.  I'm not sure where to look next to try to find the root of the problem.

Comment: What DNS errors were they?

Comment: The failure description is
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name. This could be caused by one or more of the following:
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller.
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that these machines have been failing to apply Group Policy during startup for awhile-- likely long before you made your Software Restriction Policy-related changes yesterday.

I've seen a reasonable number of [Windows 7 clients intermittently failing to apply Group Policy during startup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2421599) in the last 12 - 18 months. The machines have been a mix of Dell and HP machines (both laptop and desktop computers). In most cases updated network interface card drivers have resolved the issue, but in some extreme cases I've been forced to set the `GpNetworkStartTimeoutPolicyValue` registry value that the linked article describes. (This is, of course, after making sure that the switch ports are configure for spanning tree "portfast", etc.)

I'd troubleshoot the Event ID 1055 as described in the linked article as a first step.

Comment: In addition to what @Evan suggested, as a general Group Policy troubleshooting step for isolated errors, I would almost always recommend you first try clearing out the policy cache. See https://macgyveritblog.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/recreate-the-local-group-policy-cache-in-windows/ for instructions.

Comment: @Evan Anderson The issue of failing to obtain the policies is unique to the computer policies, and even occurs after running a gpupdate /force /target:computer.  User policies are still successful.

Comment: @MooseBalm - Okay. Your question seemed to be about failing software installation policy, which would be a computer policy applying in boot. What you're describing is exactly what I've been seening and discussed in my answer.

Comment: @Evan Anderson - I understand where the confusion is coming from.  When I say I am deploying MSI packages, I am using PDQ to push them out, not a GPO.  After updating the driver on the NIC and adding that 60 second timeout policy, it has not resolved the issue.